# c++ crashing on incrementing an unsigned long int

Tags: c++, variables, crash, integer

This one is WTF city.

The below program is crashing after a few thousand loops.

```
unsigned long int nTurn = 1;
bool quit = false;

int main(){
    while(!quit){
        doTurn();
        ++nTurn;
    }
}
```

That's, of course, simplified from my game, but nTurn is at the moment used *nowhere* but the incrementing of it, and when I comment out the ++nTurn line, the program will reliably loop forever. Shouldn't it run into the millions?

WTF, stackoverflow?

Comment: More information, please. Is the crashing code literally in `main`, or is it in a class method? What does `doTurn()` do? What is its declaration? When you run your program in a debugger, precisely which line crashes? What does "crash" mean?  Without knowing anything else, my guess is that the above code is actually in a method, and `this` has become corrupted by a wild pointer in an unrelated piece of code.

Comment: What's happening inside `doTurn()`. Something in there could be scribbling on the stack/heap.

Comment: where else is `nTurn` used? you need it for what?

Comment: doTurn() iterates through a number of class instances in a set to run their simple random wander function - and the increment is in the "move player" function triggered on keypress. The crash happens even if I move it to main(), and the game will wander the monsters forever if i remove ++nTurn

Comment: I don't use nTurn yet - but I am going to need to count turns. If it's a memory allocation thing, should I just start nTurn at 4,000,000 and subtract from it, then determine the turn number by 4mil - nTurn? or would that not change things

Comment: On modern computers, it could run into the billions.  (2^31-1 is a common upper limit for long ints.)  Even then, nTurn will usually just wrap around and become super-negative.

Comment: Also try to refrain from the attitude yielding "WTF" statements. 90% of the time even for senior programmers YOU are at fault, excuses do not clarify the problem or yield solutions.

Comment: and the crash happens at the `++nTurn;` line? what if you comment out everything inside `doTurn()`?

Comment: I commented out the doTurn() line entirely and it still happens. Running from zero it makes it to 8096 and locks at "80" - running from 8095 it makes it around 200 iterations, locks up, and disappears leaving a blank sdlout.txt

Comment: "Process terminated with status -805306369", by the way

Comment: wth... so is this code: `int main(){ while(!quit){++nTurn;}}` crashing? That's really a very strange problem.

Comment: Go to http://ideone.com/ and run your code there. Then get back to us and tell us how it went. (Also, post the link to your ideone code.)

Comment: is `nTurn` declared exactly like that? isn't it maybe an extern that you're actually defining in a different file (maybe as some other type...)? Is this the absolute very only `nTurn` you have, ever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is elsewhere.

Some other part of the program is reading from a wild pointer that ends up pointing to `nTurn`, and when this loop changes the value the other code acts different.  Or there's a race condition, and the increment makes this loop take just a tiny bit longer so the race-y thing doesn't cause trouble.  There are an infinite number of things you could have wrong elsewhere.

Can you run your program under valgrind?  Some errors it won't find, but a lot it will.

Comment: Okay so I ran my actual example code in an isolated project and it goes forever... how do I protect nTurn so that nothing can change it?

Comment: @motioneffector: "Data breakpoint".  It'll find both code changing it and code reading it that shouldn't be.

Comment: @motioneffector so, what was the problem? this got me very curious.

Comment: I can't seem to set data breakpoints in code::blocks - still trying to figure it out. but I've discovered that it crashes quicker if i run a bunch of ram-heavy programs and video players etc.

Comment: it is somehow putting nTurn out in the wild and allowing anything and everything to stomp all over it.

Answer (score 0):

may sound silly, but, if I were looking at this, I'd perhaps output the nTurn var and see if it were always crashing out on the value. then, perhaps initialize nTurn to that & see if that also causes it. you could always put this into debug and see what is happening with various registers and so forth. did you try different compilers ?

Comment: I checked, and it crashes halfway through 8097 - it outputs up to 8096, and then outputs "80" and locks up.

Comment: Okay - ran it from 8095 and it makes it to about 8200ish before it dies.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a debugger to catch the fault and see the value of nTurn. Or if you have core dump from the crash load it into the debugger to see the var values at the crash time.

One more point, could the problem be when nTurn wraps round and goes to zero?

Comment: Running from zero it makes it to 8096 and locks at "80" - running from 8095 it makes it around 200 iterations, locks up, and disappears leaving a blank sdlout.txt

Answer (score 0):

++nTurn can't be the source of the crash directly. You may have some sort of buffer overflow causing the memory for the nTurn variable to be accessed by pointer arithmetic when it shouldn't be. That would cause weird behavior when combined with the incrementing.